# Getting a 302 http redirect location with Databinder-Dispatch

Tags: scala, http-headers, databinder, scala-dispatch

With [databinder-dispatch](https://github.com/n8han/Databinder-Dispatch) 0.8.3 I'm trying to get the redirect url from a 302 http response, but I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: dispatch.StatusCode: Unexpected response code: 302
```

Here's what I've attempted, with [some help](http://sourced.implicit.ly/net.databinder/dispatch-http/0.8.3/ConfiguredHttpClient.scala.html):

```
import dispatch._
import org.apache.http.{HttpRequest,HttpResponse}
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus._

val http = new Http { 

  override def make_client = { 
    val client = new ConfiguredHttpClient(new Http.CurrentCredentials(None))

    client.setRedirectStrategy(new org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy {      
        override def isRedirected(req: HttpRequest, res: HttpResponse, ctx: HttpContext) = false 
    })

    client 
  }
}

val req: Request = :/("graph.facebook.com") / "kmels" / "picture" 

val pictureURL: String = http(req.secure >:> { _("Location").head }) //error prone code, but we're just testing. This is the line where the exception is thrown.
```

What am I missing? as always, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
val pictureURL: String = http.x(req.secure >:> { _("Location").head })
```